# How to search by different variations on Algolia?

Tags: algolia

Let's say i have records of people with names like:

```
[
  { name: "Joe Smith" },
  { name: "Mary Cage" },
  { name: "Jenn Blair" }
]
```

If i used MySQL, i'd easily do something like:

```
WHERE name LIKE %Smith% OR name LIKE %Blair%
```

That will return two records (1 for Joe Smith and 1 for Jenn Blair).

How do I do the same with Algolia? I have tried queries like `Smith OR Blair` but they return nothing!

Comment: Hey @Ryan, did my answer solve your issue? If yes, please consider accepting it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Algolia has no syntax for query conditions like this, by default all terms in `query` will be searched in your records.

However, you can do this with the `optionalWords` query parameter, which Algolia will use to remove words from the query:

`optionalWords="Smith Blair"`
`query="Smith Blair"`

This will return all records matching either "Smith" or "Blair".